# Need help understanding Javascript's .match method

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I understand that `.match()` returns an array of the matches, or null if none are found. But how do I go about accessing the values of capturing groups used with .match?

For example:

```
var val = whatever.match('(?:^|;) ?' + stuff + '=([^;]*)(?:;|$)');
```

Assuming the regular expression matches more than once, how do I access the value of the capturing group in a particular match?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use array notation: `[0]`, `[1]`, etc.

```
var val = whatever.match('(?:^|;) ?' + stuff + '=([^;]*)(?:;|$)');
if(val != null) {
    var first = val[0];
    //...
}
```

Comment: Right, but if the regex matches more than one item, val itself is already an array right? So then val[0] would just return the first match.

Comment: Correct. If the returned value from `match` is non-null, it is an array.

Comment: your guys' dialogue cleared up just what was confusing me just now. Thanks.